# My script doesn't work properly and doesn't throw an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just trying to make a button that slides up and down with jQuery but it works only 50% of the time. When I press "Slide up" it does work but it doesn't work with "Slide down". It doesn't give me any errors too...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var test = true
        var test2 = false
        if(test == true){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn1").click(function(){
                    $("p").slideUp();
                });
            });
        }
        else if(test2 == false){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn2").click(function(){
                    $("p").slideDown();
                });
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello Uranus</p>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think I'm overlooking something or I just suck at coding but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the basic javascript development ;)

`If - Else`

If your first condition is true the `else` will be not executed.
If you want to have your all button working just do :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btn1").click(function(){
                $("p").slideUp();
            });
            $(".btn2").click(function(){
                $("p").slideDown();
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuery [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('p').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<p>Hello Uranus</p>
<button class="btn">Slide Up/Down</button>
```

Comment: thanks but I need another button to slide it up but got it working

Answer (score 0):

remove the "else" from your code

Comment: thnx for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if and else. Check this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/wnwrnbw7/

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
      $("p").slideUp();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
          $("p").slideDown();
    });
  });
  </script>
<body>
  <p>Hello Uranus</p>
  <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
  <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are preventing this from happening. Just remove the conditions altogether.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn1").click(function(){
                    $("p").slideUp();
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn2").click(function(){
                    $("p").slideDown();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello Uranus</p>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done lots of `syntax` mistakes, as well as `logical`. So, i have solved those. Please replace your script with mine::

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn1").click(function () {
            $("p").slideUp();
        });
        $(".btn2").click(function () {
            $("p").slideDown();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">

     </head>
     <body>
     <p>Hello Uranus</p>
         <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
         <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
     </body>
     <script src="../public/js/jq.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script>
      function toggle(flag){
        if (flag ==1) {
          $('p').slideUp();
        }else {
          $('p').slideDown();
        }
      }
      $('.btn1').click(function(){
        toggle(1);
      });
      $('.btn2').click(function(){
        toggle(0);
      });
     </script>

</html>
```

> Note : Try this code include you jquery file.